# Can't launch ubuntu-software / QSnapStore

Tags: apt, updates, snap

Everytime I try to check any Category I'm facing this error.Screen was taken in Ubuntu-Software but I have the same error code in QSnapStore.
What can I do with it?

[Screen of an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXIKC.png)

UPD 1: Snap is not working in terminal too.When I'm trying to write "Snap refresh" - nothing happens

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnnKj.png)

Comment: Looks like an issue connecting to the Snap server. Is this issue only happening in the graphical software program, or does the issue also happen when you try to run commands like `snap refresh` or `snap install` in a terminal? Please edit the question and clarify this.

Comment: nothing happens when I'm trying to write "snap refresh",same with "snap install",
You are right,something is wrong with connecting to Snap server

Comment: Snapcraft, which Ubuntu Software uses in the background, is experiencing intermittent outages today due to a firewall issue on their part. You can see how it got HTTP 500 errors (server error) when trying to access `api.snapcraft.io`.  It should be back up-and-running soon (hopefully).